# HOW TO DRAW YAMAZUMI CHARTS USING VB.NET

Tags: charts

I Want to draw a Yamazumi charts in VB.net. This Yamazumi chart are a very special stacked column chart in which the entire data from a series is drawn one above the other data - as a series of boxes. This is the only difference.

But as of now, none of the charts give this facility. All of them put a data from a series one after another in the x axis. I do hope you get an idea of the Yamazumi thing vis a vis a regular stacked column chart!

I do not want to invest time to do it from GDI or using Paint etc. I want this chart to be done using a chart control..as such it is just not possible to do so with the current 'series' data logic.

Kindly help or give your suggestions.

Renga

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll not find a charting solution that draws this type of chart directly. However it is pretty much easy to model if the chart supports empty data points. In this case the code will have to do this:

1. Determine the maximum number of data points in each series.
2. Create a matrix with the following dimensions (number of series, max num of datapoints)
3. Fill the whole matrix with DBNull.Value (or whatever value the chart treats as empty).
4. Take the n-th series in the matrix and copy it to the n-th column there.
5. Import the matrix into the chart, where each row is a separate stacked bar series.

The above can of course be optimized, but this is the main idea how to "invert" the data.